# Are there any "if" commands like "\ifnum" in LaTeX?

Tags: conditionals

Are there any commands containing "if", similar to `\ifnum`, preferably in LaTeX (rathar than TeX)?
For example, is there anything like `\ifstring`? (I am not after `\ifstring` only, I want to know which options are available, if any).

Comment: See also: [LaTeX conditional expression](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/)

Comment: It's now a dozen year later and I still can't find an answer to the question of whether there is an \ifstring that will test if something is a string. Note that I'm not asking to test if two strings are equal - I'm asking for something that would behave as follows:
\ifstring{this is \textbf{bold}}{true}{false} would evaluate to false
\ifstring{this is a string}{true}{false} would evaluate to true.
\ifstring{this has math $a=b$ in it}{true}{false} should be predictable.

Basically if the argument to \ifstring contains any macros that need expansion, then it should evaluate to false.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `\if...` commands are mostly TeX primitives (with `\newif` it's possible to define other conditionals).

There is something like `\ifstring`, but it uses `\ifnum`; the command `\pdfstrcmp` takes two strings as argument and compares it, returning -1 if the first precedes the second (in the lexicographic order based on ASCII codes), 0 if the strings are equal and 1 otherwise. The usual ways to exploit it are

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{string1}{string2}=0
   <code if the strings are equal>
\else
   <code if the strings are different>
\fi
```

or

```
\ifcase\pdfstrcmp{string1}{string2}%
   <code if the strings are equal>
\or
   <code if string2 comes after string1>
\else
   <code if string1 comes before string2>
\fi
```

In XeTeX there's `\strcmp` that does the same; loading **pdftexcmds** one can use `\pdf@strcmp` with pdftex, xetex and luatex.

In the pseudocodes above "string1" and "string2" can be also macros, which will be expanded similarly to what happens with `\edef` and at the end (when no more expansions can be performed) the tokens are "detokenized" for the comparison (so `\relax` becomes a six character string followed by a space; for example `\pdfstrcmp{\relax}{\string\relax\space}` returns 0).

Comment: @egreg: if I recall correctly, they don't have to expand to characters only: the result of their full expansion is converted to a string (I think, through the same code as `\detokenize`).

Comment: @Bruno: I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Nitpick regarding the parenthetical remark in the first paragraph: `\newif` doesn't really make new conditionals. It merely provides a handy way to assign one of the existing conditionals `\iffalse` and `\iftrue` to a control sequence.

Comment: @Harald: it depends on the point of view. They are new for the programmer, they aren't for TeX, which sees only `\iftrue` or `\iffalse`.

Answer (score 17):

The `etoolbox` package has a lot conditional commands which goes beyond those TeX primitives. Have a look at the manual you will find they very usefull.

Comment: In particular there is `\ifstrequal{str1}{str2}{true}{false}`, and many many others. The `etoolbox` is definitely a must for anyone trying to do any kind of “programatic” work in (La)TeX.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative is [`expl3`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3). The basic language layer of LaTeX3 provides several conditionals. To handle strings you can use the function `\str_if_eq:nnTF`. 
Next to this conditional `expl3` provides also a case function for `strings` named `\str_case:nn(TF)`.

`\str_if_eq:nnTF` has the following syntax:

```
\str_if_eq:nnTF { <test string 1> } { <test string 2> }
 { <True Code> }
 { <False Code> }
```

`\str_case:nn(TF)` has the following syntax:

```
\str_case:nnTF { <test string> }
 { 
   { string case 1 } { code case 1 }
   { string case 2 } { code case 2 }
   ...
   { string case n } { code case n }
 }
 { <additional TRUE code> }
 { <FALSE case> }
```

(Either one of the `T` or `F` branches may be omitted provided the matching argument letter is also.)

[The complete manual](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23914/where-can-i-find-the-latex3-manual)

Comment: Note that ultimately this is using the same `\(pdf)strcmp` primitive discussed by egreg in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using the [xstring](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package for these kind of situations. See for example [Using xstring to check .tex file name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19406/using-xstring-to-check-tex-file-name).

Answer (score 0):

To compare 2 strings, that is string-version of `\ifnum` of TeX:

```
%https://tex.loria.fr/general/texbytopic.pdf
\def\ifstring#1#2{%
\def\testa{#1}%
\def\testb{#2}%
\ifx\testa\testb%
}%
```