# Where can I find the LaTeX3 manual?

Tags: documentation, latex3, expl3

Few month ago I saw a big pdf-manual of all LaTeX3-packages and the new syntax. I think it was bigger than 300 pages. I can't find it on the web.

Does anyone have a link?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are probably looking for the documented sources of the [l3kernel](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) package(s).

Answer (score 22):

What you probably have seen was a typeset version of all the [l3kernel](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) commands and their implementation (which actually is more than 500 pages) a document named `source3.pdf`. I would suggest to read through this **only after** being familiar with the programming language for LaTeX3 (if ever). Instead read the other documents in l3kernel, in particular `interface3.pdf`. Reasons are given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24932/moving-to-latex3-for-package-authors).

Beside the kernel documentation you will find additional material in [l3packages](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3packages) and [l3experimental](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3experimental). As the name indicates "l3experimental" contains material that we are experimenting with. It should be stable in the sense that we believe it is working properly, but we are evaluating aspects of user interface, functionality etc. Feedback is therefore very welcome.

(We also have some l3trial bundle, but that is not placed on CTAN as it contains direct work in progress --- for those interested you can see that stuff in our [svn source](http://www.latex-project.org/code.html) or its [github mirror](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror)  --- again feedback and suggestions are welcome, but please no "xyz doesn't seem to work ..." that certainly can be the case in that area.)