# Write with expl3 | 1) How to properly write the initialization part with expl3 syntax?

Tags: expl3, latex3

> As stated in [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586494/194994), I wish to switch my class
> written with LaTeX2e to the `expl3` syntax. I will try to do this by
> asking a series of questions, collecting code examples, making the
> transition *gradually* (quoting @PhelypeOleinik). In this way, I'll be
> able to reduce the risk of violating `expl3` conventions.

I begin with the initialization part, for example processing options and loading classes. What is the proper way to achieve the effect of the following code with `expl3` syntax?

```
% (Package initialization)
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{packagename}
    [2021/03/09 ...]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
family = packagename,
prefix = packagename@
}
\DeclareBoolOption[false]{off}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax
```

```
% (Class initialization)
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{classname}
    [2021/03/09 ...]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family = classname,
    prefix = classname@,
    setkeys= \kvsetkeys,
}
\DeclareStringOption[some-string]{option-name}
\DeclareStringOption{option-with-no-default-value}
\DeclareVoidOption{other-string}{\kvsetkeys{classname}{option-name = other-string}}

\DeclareDefaultOption{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\classname@baseclass}}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax

\LoadClass{\classname@baseclass}
```

Maybe there're better ways with `expl3`, I'm just including these LaTeX2e code as a comparison.

Comment: you are starting at the wrong place. Most of these commands have either no expl3 version or are (like the keys) not trivial to replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something to give you a start.  That part of the code is mostly option handling, so I suggest you take a look at the [`l3keys` module documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#chapter.26) which covers the available key handlers.  I'll explain very briefly, because there are a *lot* of small concepts here in this piece of code.

First we start by declaring the format needed, and loading `l3keys2e` for the class option parsing:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
```

then we declare the class (or package):

```latex
\ProvidesExplClass{classname}
  {2021/03/09} {1.0} {My class to learn expl3}
```

The command `\ProvidesExpl<thing>` already does `\ExplSyntaxOn` for you, and takes care of switching it off at the end of the class/package, so this is the proper way to start an `expl3`-based class.

Now define a constant string (constant means it shouldn't be changed with `\str_set:Nn` or something like that) to hold the base class name.  The prefix `\c_...` indicates it is a constant (`l` is local and `g` is global), and the suffix `..._str` means it's a string variable:

```latex
\str_const:Nn \c__classname_base_class_str { book }
```

Now we'll define some options for your class called `classname`:

```latex
\keys_define:nn { classname }
  {
```

First what `kvoptions` calls a string option (one which takes a value):

```latex
    % \DeclareStringOption
    , option-name .tl_set:N = \l__classname_option_name_tl
    , option-name .initial:n = { some-string }
```

you use it as `option-name` and the value given to it will be stored in `\l__classname_option_name_tl` (a `l`ocal `tl` variable).  The initial value is `some-string`.  One peculiarity of `\keys_define:nn` is that it already creates the variables for you, so you don't need to do `\tl_new:N \l__classname_option_name_tl` beforehand (but it doesn't hurt either).

Now what `kvoptions` calls a void option, one which just executes a piece of code:

```latex
    % \DeclareVoidOption
    , other-string .code:n =
        { \keys_set:nn { classname } { option-name = other-string } }
```

When used, the `other-string` option will do the same as `option-name=other-string`.

Now a boolean option, whose initial value is `false`:

```latex
    % \DeclareBoolOption
    , off .bool_set:N = \l__classname_off_bool
    , off .initial:n = { false }
```

And finally, you tell `l3str` how to handle unknown options:

```latex
    % \DeclareDefaultOption
    , unknown .code:n =
        {
          \iow_term:x
            {
              Passing~option~\CurrentOption \c_space_tl to~
              \str_use:N \c__classname_base_class_str
            }
          \PassOptionsToClass { \CurrentOption } { \c__classname_base_class_str }
        }
  }
```

It will print "Passing option  to " in the terminal. `\iow_term:n` writes to the terminal, and `\iow_term:x` does an "e`x`haustive expansion" of the argument before passing it to the underlying `n` variant.

Now process the options and load the base class:

```latex
\ProcessKeysOptions { classname }
\LoadClass { \c__classname_base_class_str }
```

As an example code, you can use `\bool_if:NTF` to test a boolean variable:

```latex
\bool_if:NTF \l__classname_off_bool
  { \iow_term:n { off~true } }
  { \iow_term:n { off~false } }
```

and again `\iow_term:x` to write to the terminal:

```latex
\iow_term:x { Value~of~option-name:~\tl_use:N \l__classname_option_name_tl }
```

---

Putting it all together:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{classname.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ProvidesExplClass{classname}
  {2021/03/09} {1.0} {My class to learn expl3}

\str_const:Nn \c__classname_base_class_str { book }

\keys_define:nn { classname }
  {
    % \DeclareStringOption
    , option-name .tl_set:N = \l__classname_option_name_tl
    , option-name .initial:n = { some-string }
    % \DeclareVoidOption
    , other-string .code:n =
        { \keys_set:nn { classname } { option-name = other-string } }
    % \DeclareBoolOption
    , off .bool_set:N = \l__classname_off_bool
    , off .initial:n = { false }
    % \DeclareDefaultOption
    , unknown .code:n =
        {
          \iow_term:x
            {
              Passing~option~\CurrentOption \c_space_tl to~
              \str_use:N \c__classname_base_class_str
            }
          \PassOptionsToClass { \CurrentOption } { \c__classname_base_class_str }
        }
  }
\ProcessKeysOptions { classname }
\LoadClass { \c__classname_base_class_str }

% example code:
\bool_if:NTF \l__classname_off_bool
  { \iow_term:n { off~true } }
  { \iow_term:n { off~false } }

\iow_term:x { Value~of~option-name:~\tl_use:N \l__classname_option_name_tl }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,option-name=VALUE]{classname}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```