# LaTeX 3 - How can I use it instead of the current?

Tags: latex3

Recently I updated my TeX Live distribution via the TeX Live Utility. I notice it installed three Packages: `l3experiemtal`, `l3kernel`, `l3packages` and `lt3graph`.

I was wondering if can compile my document with this `l3` packages? or are these packages just for information porpouses?
[image]

Comment: You can use them with LaTeX-2e but you could not, I don't think, compile your document using nothing but those packages. At least, as far as I know. See the documentation `ltx3info.pdf` for some information about them.

Comment: No, but many packages make use of them 'under the hood' (or not); e.g., `siunitx`, `xparse`, `l3keys`, etc.  They are designed so that you can use "LaTeX3" things in LaTeX2e.

Comment: Note that `lt3graph` is _not_ a LaTeX3 Team package: the convention is that we ask that `l3...` is left for team use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are just *packages* that provide a new - currently experimental - way of coding, almost like an interface. You still *compile* your documents with LaTeX.

You can definitely learn how to use this new coding/interface by [studying the documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23914/5764).