# Improving spacing to previous word when redefining \emph to use letter spacing

Tags: letterspacing, emphasis

The most common way to emphasise in German (and probably other) blackletter typesetting was to use letter-spacing *(Sperrsatz* in German). I am attempting to implement a way to effectively redefine the `\emph` command in such a way that it uses letter-spacing in *specific* contexts. For more information, read the background below.

### The problem

Currently, I am implementing letter-spacing emphasis by using an appropriately constructed `ItalicFont`:

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,
             CharacterVariant=81, CharacterVariant=13, HyphenChar="2010, % Needed for reasons.
             ItalicFont = UnifrakturMaguntia,
             ItalicFeatures={LetterSpace=20.0, Kerning=Off,
                             Ligatures=NoCommon, WordSpace=1.2}]
             {UnifrakturMaguntia}
```

This beautifully is able to distinguish between a blackletter or an antiqua font being used and correctly emphasises blackletter with letter-spacing and antiqua (in *all* occurrances) as italics. The main issue I have is that letter-spacing as defined here introduces additional spacing only *after* the characters. This means, the interword-space *preceeding* the `\emph{emphasised text}` command is too small, making it look like the emphasised part is connected to the previous word (see example image).

[image: Example text showing too small an interword space at the beginning of letter-spaced text.]

As a workaround, I have [redefined `\emph`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6755/16347) (see code below) to include `\xspace`. `\xspace` usually does a good job of adding additional glue if the emphasised word does not start a new line. However, I am running into obvious issues in edge cases. A few of them I have chosen to manually work around by `\unskip` for the time being but I do not like that solution.

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\xspace\em}
```

### The question

**Is there an elegant way to add additional space before an emphasised word that does not cause additional space to be added before every occurance of `\emph` as in the MWE below?**

Glue should be added *only* if the current environment is blackletter and if the word is not the first word of a line (including the beginning of a paragraph).

### The MWE (including test cases)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xspace}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true,
                 spelling=new,
                 script=fraktur]
                 {german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,
             ItalicFont=UnifrakturMaguntia,
             ItalicFeatures={LetterSpace=20.0,
                             Kerning=Off,
                             Ligatures=NoCommon,
                             WordSpace=1.2}]
             {UnifrakturMaguntia}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text]{LiberationSerif}
\newfontfamily\antiquafont[Mapping=tex-text]{LiberationSerif}

\newcommand\antiqua[1]{{\antiquafont #1}}
\newcommand\antiquaemph[1]{{\antiquafont\textit{#1}}}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\xspace\em}

\begin{document}
\section{Teſting}
\emph{Sperrſatz} am Beginn und \emph{in der Mitte} einer Zeile.
Mehr Zeichen, damit man den Zeilenumbruch ſieht.

\begin{english}
\section{\antiqua{Testing}}
\emph{Emphasis} at the beginning and \emph{in the middle} of a line.
More text so the line break can be seen. The \antiquaemph{custom command}
does not cause problems.
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

(Naturally, any two sufficiently different fonts can be used here. For reference, my blackletter font is UnifrakturMaguntia which is free and can be downloaded [from its sourceforge page](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/).)

(For simplicity, I have *not* included the [sophisticated `\antiqua` switch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65165/16347) mentioned below. Instead, I have just defined a simple `\antiqua` command which is sufficient for this MWE.)

### Background

I have a (long) XeTeX document that I wish to be able to typeset in either blackletter or antiqua depending on a true/false switch. I have already written quite a few `\emph`s (depending on whether something should change to blackletter or not) and a few `\antiquaemph`s (if it should never). This German document when set in blackletter, switches to antiqua typefaces for foreign languages (implemented by `polyglossia`’s `\englishfont` and variants) and for foreign loanwords (implemented [as shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65165/16347)).

Comment: Does `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and `\preto\emph{\ifhmode\hspace*{<length>}\fi}` work? Then you could wrap it in a boolean switch for what kind of font you're using. Of course, I'm not really sure what kind of edge cases you are stuck with

Comment: The `soul` package has a letterspacing macro `\so`. I haven't used to know if it fulfills all your requirements, but I'd bet it is worth the try. If it does, it'd be easy to redefine `\emph` to do `\so`'s job.

Comment: Indeed, your issues seem to be considered by `\so`'s implementation. The parameters used by it are stated in the form `\sodef{font}{inter-letter space}{inner space}{outer space}`.

Comment: @gusbrs -- Or, indeed, use `microtype` and its letterspacing commands (such as `\textls`). But you still need to wrap `\emph` somehow if you want it to distinguish between blackletter fonts (or environments) and other situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My earlier comment had this in mind:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}\parindent0pt % just for this example
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xspace}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true,
                 spelling=new,
                 script=fraktur]
                 {german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,
%             ItalicFont=LinBiolinumOI,
             ItalicFont=UnifrakturMaguntia,
             ItalicFeatures={LetterSpace=20.0,
                             Kerning=Off,
                             Ligatures=NoCommon,
                             WordSpace=1.2}]
%             {Linux Biolinum O}
             {UnifrakturMaguntia}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text]{LiberationSerif}
\newfontfamily\antiquafont[Mapping=tex-text]{LiberationSerif}

\newcommand\antiqua[1]{{\antiquafont #1}}
\newcommand\antiquaemph[1]{{\antiquafont\textit{#1}}}

%\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\xspace\em}
\newif\ifblackletter
\blacklettertrue

% \preto comes from the etoolbox package, which is loaded by polyglossia
\preto\emph{%
  \ifblackletter
    \ifhmode\kern1pt % how big of a 'space' do you want to add?
    \fi\fi}

\AtBeginEnvironment{english}{\blackletterfalse}


\begin{document}
\section{Teſting}
\emph{Sperrſatz} am Beginn und \emph{in der Mitte} einer Zeile.
Mehr Zeichen, damit man den Zeilenumbruch ſieht.

\begin{english}
\section{\antiqua{Testing}}
\emph{Emphasis} at the beginning and \emph{in the middle} of a line.
More text so the line break can be seen. The \antiquaemph{custom command}
does not cause problems.
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image: blackletter emphasis example]

Comment: This looks very promising! Coincidentally, a corresponding `\ifblackletter` already exists in my document. I’ll do some testing probably tomorrow to see how it works out. Sorry for ‘disappearing’ after asking; a few other issues had popped up so I didn’t have time to come back here.