# String comparisons not working with textgreek

Tags: math-mode, conditionals, greek, strings

Following the solution from this question as a guide - [Are there any "if" commands like "\ifnum" in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22923/are-there-any-if-commands-like-ifnum-in-latex) - I have setup a newcommand to perform a string comparison.  Unfortunately I can't get greek characters from the `textgreek` package to compare.

The following MWE shows that a math mode alpha can be compared, but because my Greek characters are part of protein names I can't use math mode definitions because of the italics.  I can't override the math mode definitions to remove the italics because I still want this when I actually use mathematical formulas.

I would like either:

1. a greek character alternative
2. a string comparison that will work with `textgreek`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{siunitx,microtype,textcomp,textgreek}

\newcommand{\evaltest}[2]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}=0
        #1 equals #2%
    \else
        #1 does not equal #2%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \evaltest{a}{b}
        \item \evaltest{a}{a}
        \item \evaltest{a a}{a a}
        \item $\alpha$
        \item \evaltest{$\alpha$}{$\alpha$}
        \item \textalpha
        %\item \evaltest{\textalpha}{\textalpha}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\pdfstrcmp` primitive performs expansion: the linked answer does mention that the argument needs to be a 'string'. For comparing arbitrary input, prevent expansion using `\unexpanded`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{siunitx,microtype,textcomp,textgreek}

\newcommand{\evaltest}[2]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=0
        #1 equals #2%
    \else
        #1 does not equal #2%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \evaltest{a}{b}
        \item \evaltest{a}{a}
        \item \evaltest{a a}{a a}
        \item $\alpha$
        \item \evaltest{$\alpha$}{$\alpha$}
        \item \textalpha
        \item \evaltest{\textalpha}{\textalpha}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

(The expansion is much like `\edef` so anything that is safe in the latter is also safe in `\pdfstrcmp`. That can be useful but it's not here!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I did notice in the linked question that the answer said it compared strings, but it was this part of the  answer that I was getting stuck on:  `In the pseudocodes above "string1" and "string2" can be also macros`.  I was attributing `\textalpha` the status of a macro that would be expanded as the way I understood it, just like `\edef`.

Comment: @EngBIRD They can be macros but only if they expand safely inside an `\edef`. Like many TeX macros, that's not the case for `\textalpha`.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be `pdfstrcmp`? If not, you should look into `etoolbox`. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx,microtype,textcomp,textgreek}

\newcommand{\evaltest}[2]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}=0
        #1 equals #2%
    \else
        #1 does not equal #2%
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\etest}[2]{%
  \ifdefequal{#1}{#2}{#1 equals #2}{#1 does not equal #2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \evaltest{a}{b}
        \item \evaltest{a}{a}
        \item \evaltest{a a}{a a}
        \item $\alpha$
        \item \evaltest{$\alpha$}{$\alpha$}
        \item \textalpha
        \item \etest{\textalpha}{\textalpha}
        \item \etest{\textalpha}{\textbeta}
        \item \etest{\textbeta}{\textbeta}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am willing to switch to `ifdefequal`.  Can this function be made more robust however?  While it technically answers my question, I didn't expect the answer to break some currently successful comparisons.  As included in the itemized list any of the tests with a space, or in mathmode no longer work.

Comment: @EngBIRD -- Oh, good point. The 'def' in `\ifdefequal` indicates it compares macro definitions.  `\textalpha` is not the same as the string `a a`. I should've put more forethought into this answer..!