# Problem with command expansion

Tags: expansion

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\convertlang}[1]{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{es}{spanish}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{lat}{latin}{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{eng}{english}{%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{deu}{german}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{enm}{spanish}{% else
          % use English as foreign default
          english}}}}}}%

\newcommand*{\langtest}[1]{%
    \def\temp{\convertlang{#1}}%
    \ifstrequal{\temp}{spanish}{True}{False}%
}

\begin{document}

Testing: \convertlang{es} % yields: spanish

\langtest{es} % should yield: True

\end{document}
```

The command `\convertlang` takes an ISO 8859 language code (`es`, `eng`, etc.) and converts it into a babel language name (`spanish`, `english`, etc.). This works fine.

The problem is with `\langtest`, which compares a string (`spanish`) with the result of transforming its argument (`#1`) using `\convertlang`.

There must be a problem in the expansion of `\convertlang` and/or of `#1` there, buy I don't understand the fundamentals of TeX macro expansion.

I tried doing this:

```
\newcommand*{\langtest}[1]{%
    \edef\temp{\convertlang{#1}}%
    \ifstrequal{\temp}{spanish}{True}{False}%
}
```

expecting that `\temp` gets the expanded value of its argument. But this doesn't work either.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the expandable and expanding string equality test `\pdfstrcmp` (for portability use `\pdf@strcmp` from `pdftexcmds`, see for example [Are there any "if" commands like "\ifnum" in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22923/35864)). That command expands its test arguments and is itself expandable. (The latter is always nice, the former is not *always* convenient [cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230878/35864], but is what we want here.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfStrEqualTF}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\convertlang}[1]{%
  \IfStrEqualTF{#1}{es}
    {spanish}
    {\IfStrEqualTF{#1}{lat}
       {latin}
       {\IfStrEqualTF{#1}{eng}
          {english}
          {\IfStrEqualTF{#1}{deu}
            {german}
            {\IfStrEqualTF{#1}{enm}
               {spanish}
               {english}}}}}}

\newcommand*{\langtest}[1]{%
  \IfStrEqualTF{\convertlang{#1}}{spanish}
    {True}
    {False}}

\begin{document}
Testing: \convertlang{es} % yields: spanish

\langtest{es} % should yield: True

\langtest{en} % should yield: False
\end{document}
```

[image: Testing: spanish//True//False]

---

Some more details about the MWE and why it doesn't do the desired thing.

**First** of all, `etoolbox`'s `\ifstrequal` is defined with `\newrobustcmd`. It is therefore robust and not expandable. That means that

```
\edef\temp{\convertlang{#1}}
```

does not actually save the long language name in `\temp` as we would have hoped. It just saves a cascade of `\ifstrequal` tests. This means that `\temp` does not contain a simple string.

```
\edef\temp{\convertlang{es}}%
\show\temp
```

gives

> ```
> > \temp=macro:
> ->\ifstrequal {es}{es}{spanish}{\ifstrequal {es}{lat}{latin}{\ifstrequal {es}{eng}{english}{\ifstrequal {es}{deu}{german}{\ifstrequal {es}{enm}{spanish}{english}}}}}.
> ```

You need a string equality test that is expandable to allow `\convertlang{#1}` to expand to the language name in an `\edef`.

`\pdf@strcmp` comes in handy here, since its string comparison *is* expandable, meaning that a command defined via this equality test can expand to the result of the comparisons in an `\edef`.

The **second** issue is that `\ifstrequal` doesn't expand its arguments, so even if `\temp` contained only a string, the test wouldn't quite work as intended

```
\def\temp{spanish}%
\ifstrequal{\temp}{spanish}{True}{False}%
```

still gives 'False', since `\temp` *is* not a string equal to `spanish`, it *expands* to a string equal to `spanish`, that is a small but significant difference.

There are several possible ways around that. Depending on what you can guarantee about `\temp` it would be enough to say

```
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\temp}{spanish}{True}{False}%
```

or

```
\ifdefstring{\temp}{spanish}{True}{False}%
```

if you know that `\temp` expands to a string in one expansion step. If more steps are required or you want full expansion, other tricks are needed.

`\pdf@strcmp` helps here, because it just completely expands its argument. This means that as long as `\temp` does not contain anything that blows up in an expansion context, its 'ultimate expanded string value' can be compared. You need not worry about expanding it first for the test.

Comment: Thanks. But why does my code not work?

Comment: @NVaughan I'm just writing an edit explaining that in more detail.

Comment: Also, I read that pdftexcmds is aimed for LuaTex?

Comment: @NVaughan Yes and no. `pdftexcmds` provides primitives that are not defined in all engines by default in a way that it can be uniformly accessed by all engines. If you are only using pdfTeX you could use `\pdfstrcmp` but that would fail in LuaTeX. With `pdftexcmds` we can use `\pdf@strcmp`, which works everywhere.

Comment: Oh, good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much. There are things I still don't fully grasp, but the code works, and I can start researching from there.

Comment: @NVaughan feel free to ask small questions here in the comments if the answer is unclear. I have to go now, but I will be happy to address them later. If you have 'bigger' questions, it may be better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use the simpler interface of `expl3` with `\str_case:nnF`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertlang}{m}
 {
  \nvaughan_convertlang:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \nvaughan_convertlang:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {es}{spanish}
    {lat}{latin}
    {eng}{english}
    {deu}{german}
    {enm}{spanish}
   }
   {english}
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\langtest}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \nvaughan_convertlang:n { #1 } } { spanish } { True } { False }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Testing: \convertlang{es} % yields: spanish

\langtest{es} should yield: True

\langtest{lat} should yield: False 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh gosh! There are so many options! Thanks @egreg.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use long nested if-tests. This is difficult to expand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c__nvaughan_convert_es_tl{spanish}
\tl_const:Nn \c__nvaughan_convert_lat_tl{latin}
\tl_const:Nn \c__nvaughan_convert_eng_tl{english}
\tl_const:Nn \c__nvaughan_convert_deu_tl{german}
\tl_const:Nn \c__nvaughan_convert_enm_tl{spanish}

\newcommand*{\convertlang}[1]
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF {c__nvaughan_convert_#1_tl}
   { \tl_use:c {c__nvaughan_convert_#1_tl} }
   { english}
 } 

\newcommand*{\langtest}[1]{%
   \str_if_eq:eeTF {\convertlang{#1}}{spanish}
   {True}{False}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

Testing: \convertlang{es} % yields: spanish
\convertlang{lat} \convertlang{blub}

\langtest{es} % should yield: True

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike Fischer. Where can I find a guide to these LaTeX3 commands?

Comment: in interface3.pdf.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a look. When you said, "This is difficult to expand", did you mean that it take more processing resources, or that it is prone to faults.

Comment: I mean that it is difficult to add more languages as you would have to nest deeper and deeper, while when using commands like above a new language is simply  on more line. (It is faster too, as tex doesn't have to do so many comparisions).

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.